# WC() is giving empty results in WooCommerce 3.7

Tags: php, wordpress, object, methods, woocommerce

Call to `WC()` is not returning required values in `WC()->customer` giving empty results.

The sample code I am using is:

```
$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

$country  = $customer->get_shipping_country();

if ( $country ) {

    WC()->customer->set_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );

    WC()->customer->set_shipping_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't change your question code in reaction to my answer. You should keep your original question code. You can live me a feed back in the comment area below my answer, I will appreciate it.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec After updating woocommerce from 3.5.3 to 3.7 ,I am facing many issues like  getting empty wc() object, for customer, shipping, cart etc..not in customer alone..urgent help is needed.

Comment: So this is a bug that you should report in Github Woocommerce… So as I have commented at the end of my answer, you should better revert back to a stable WooCommerce 3.6.x version. Version 3.7 is fairly new and still with a lot of bugs as always when a new major release comes out. Also **you should always test major updates on a stage web site**, before updating a production web site.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I haven't updated woocommerce in a while...and the problem exists in my 3.6.5 version also....only in calls via rest api..could you please tell me what's wrong in using wc() as before

Comment: Sorry rest Api is quiet complicated depending on the version you are using and how you are using it… Now in general `WC()` is mostly used on front end. You might try the old way which is: `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->customer` or `$woocommerce->cart`. For example I have noticed that some methods work with `new WC_Customer( $user_id );` but not with `WC()->customer`…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Sorry to say that I had already tested with $woocommerce and its not working. Main issue is when we add an item to cart. WC() classes are not getting required results.                               WC()->customer->set_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );
WC()->customer->set_shipping_location( $country, $state, $postcode, $city );
WC()->customer->set_billing_address_to_base();
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_to_base();                                 These methods are not getting. I replaced WC() with $woocommerce. Still no result. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, instead of `WC()->customer` use your `$customer` variable which is already the `WC_Customer` Object defined by `$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );`.

Also `$state`, `$postcode` and `$city` variables are not defined in your code *(`$postcode` and `$city` are optional as they are predefined with empty values see the source code [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Legacy_Customer.html#92-103) and [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer.html#833-852))*.

To finish you need to save the data using `WC_Data` `save()` method.

So your code will be:

```
$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

$country  = $customer->get_shipping_country();
$state    = $customer->get_shipping_state();

if ( $country ) {

    $customer->set_location( $country, $state );
    $customer->set_shipping_location( $country, $state );

    $customer->save(); // Save the data to the database
}
```

This should better work now.

> **Note:** You should always wait **at least one or two month** before installing a WooCommerce major release, as there is always bugs that will be solved afterwards in the next minor updates releases. This will avoid you many problems and waste of time. 
>   So yo should better **revert back** to stable WooCommerce 3.6.5 version and wait 2 month at minima.